# Trying to turn multiple spaces into one space

Tags: c

I am trying to print back the user's input with the modification that anytime there are more than one spaces in a row in the user input, the output will only show one space.  For instance, if I wrote

```
Hey,     I love Stack Overflow
```

I would want my output to be

```
Hey, I love Stack Overflow
```

I saw some answers on this but they weren't in C and weren't following my logic which I feel like could work.

```
int c, count;
c = 0;
count = 0;
printf("Enter a string of characters, please: ");
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ' ')
        ++count;
    if ((count == 1) && c == ' ')
        continue;
    else
        count--;
    putchar(c);
}
```

The output when I run this code, though, does not remove excess spaces, it just outputs the exact same message.

Comment: Hint: you have to only `putchar(c)` under some condition(s). `while (...) { ... if (...) { putchar(c); } }`

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger, or flood the code with printfs, so that you can see what the code is doing.

Comment: Ask yourself, "under what conditions do I want to output a space?"  (Or "under what conditions do I want to output `c`?")  A good answer to that question will go a long way to writing the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close.
Use `count` as a flag and set to either `1` or `0` instead of using `++` and `--`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    int c = 0, count = 1;//1 to skip leading spaces
    printf ( "Enter a string of characters, please: ");
    while ( ( c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ( c == ' ') {//c is a space
            if ( count == 1 && c == ' ') {//skip extra spaces
                continue;
            }
            //if count is 0 execution will fall through and putchar will be called
            count = 1;//flag to skip extra spaces
        }
        else {//c is not a space
            count = 0;//flag to print a space
        }
        putchar ( c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but shows the approach I'd take.

```
int inSpace = 0;

printf("Enter a string of characters, please: ");
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        if (!inSpace)
        {
            putchar(c);
            inSpace = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        putchar(c);
        inSpace = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> to turn multiple spaces into one space

Consider simply noting the previous character.

```
int previous = 0;
int c;

printf("Enter a string of characters, please: ");
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  if (c != ' ' || previous != ' ')
    putchar(c);
  }
  previous = c;
}
```